# how to upload file onSubmit in React.js using FormData?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express

I am new to React.js and trying to send picture through a form to my database. I have Express.js in the back-end and React.js in the front-end. This is my App.js in React.js.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import LearningFirstComp from './components/LearningFirstComp';

class App extends Component {
 constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state={
    inputTopValue:'',
    inputBottomValue:'',
    inputImageValue: '',
  }
  this.handleTopChange = this.handleTopChange.bind(this);
  this.handleBottomChange = this.handleBottomChange.bind(this);
  this.handleImageChange = this.handleImageChange.bind(this);
  this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
}

  handleTopChange(event) {
    this.setState({inputTopValue: event.target.value});
    console.log("changing")
}

 handleBottomChange(event) {
    this.setState({inputBottomValue: event.target.value});
    console.log("descr")
}

handleImageChange(event) {
  this.setState({inputImageValue: event.target.value});
  console.log("imagechanged")
}

handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var mycoolform = new FormData();

    mycoolform.append('topstuff', event.target.topstuff.value);
    mycoolform.append('bottomstuff', event.target.bottomstuff.value);
    mycoolform.append('pic1', event.target.myimage.value)
    console.log(mycoolform)

    fetch('api/learning', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
          'Accept': 'application/json'
        },
        body: mycoolform
    })
    console.log(mycoolform,"this is the body")
    }



render() {
  return (
  <div className="App">
    <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} encType="multipart/form-data">
      <input type="text" name="topstuff" placeholder="title" onChange={this.handleTopChange} value={this.state.inputTopValue} /> <br/>
      <input type="text" name="bottomstuff" placeholder="body" onChange={this.handleBottomChange} value={this.state.inputBottomValue} /><br/>
      <input type="file" name="myimage" onChange={this.handleImageChange} value={this.state.inputImageValue} /><br/>
      <input type="submit" value="yeah boy" />
    </form>
  </div>
    );
   }
  }

export default App;
```

I have console logged the "mycoolform" variable in multiple places after I submit and the all return empty. Am I not creating the formData or appending values to it correctly? 
And also, do my headers look okay to send files and text to the database?

Comment: Why not use the values stored in the state rather than event.target.*.value when building your FormData?

Comment: You mean like this?  `mycoolform.append('topstuff', this.state.inputTopValue);`                                                                                      It doesnt really make any difference and still returning null.

Comment: `console.log`ing the FormData object doesn't actually show the contents. You will need to use one of the [FormData methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) to view the values.

Comment: Have you find a solution for this?